# jQuery AJAX call on mousemove

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mousemove

I have an image being created with gdimage, which has 40000 5x5 blocks linking to different user profiles and I want that when you hover over one of those blocks, AJAX will go and fetch that profile from the database by detecting the x and y co-ords when it is moved over the image.

Then when it is clicked, with the information it has obtained link to that users profile.

Here is what I have got so far:

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.fn.elementlocation = function() {

        var curleft = 0;
        var curtop = 0;

        var obj = this;

        do {

        curleft += obj.attr('offsetLeft');
        curtop += obj.attr('offsetTop');

        obj = obj.offsetParent();

        } while ( obj.attr('tagName') != 'BODY' );


            return ( {x:curleft, y:curtop} );

    };


    $(document).ready( function() {

        $("#gdimage").mousemove( function( eventObj ) {

            var location = $("#gdimage").elementlocation();
            var x = eventObj.pageX - location.x;
            var x_org = eventObj.pageX - location.x;
            var y = eventObj.pageY - location.y;
            var y_org = eventObj.pageY - location.y;

            x = x / 5;
            y = y / 5;

            x = (Math.floor( x ) + 1);
            y = (Math.floor( y ) + 1);

            if (y > 1) {

                block = (y * 200) - 200;
                block = block + x;

            } else {

                block = x;

            }

            $("#block").text( block );
            $("#x_coords").text( x );
            $("#y_coords").text( y );

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "fetch.php",
                    data: "x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#user_name_area").html(data.username);
                    }
                });

        });

    });

</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?

    require('connect.php');

    $mouse_x = $_GET['x'];
    $mouse_y = $_GET['y'];

    $grid_search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project WHERE project_x_cood = '$mouse_x' AND project_y_cood = '$mouse_y'") or die(mysql_error());

    $user_exists = mysql_num_rows($grid_search);

    if ($user_exists == 1) {

        $row_grid_search = mysql_fetch_array($grid_search);

        $user_id = $row_grid_search['project_user_id'];


        $get_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());

        $row_get_user = mysql_fetch_array($get_user);

        $user_name = $row_get_user['user_name'];
        $user_online = $row_get_user['user_online'];

        $json['username'] = $user_name;
        echo json_encode($json);

    } else {

        $json['username'] = $blank;
        echo json_encode($json);

    }

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tip_trigger" style="cursor: pointer;">

    <img src="gd_image.php" width="1000" height="1000" id="gdimage" />

    <div id="hover" class="tip" style="text-align: left;">
        Block No. <span id="block"></span><br />
        X Co-ords: <span id="x_coords"></span><br />
        Y Co-ords: <span id="y_coords"></span><br />
        User: <span id="user_name_area">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now, the 'block', 'x_coords' and 'y_coords' variables from the mousemove location works fine and shows in the span tags, but it's not getting the PHP variables from the AJAX function and I can't understand why.

I also don't know how to make it so when the mouse is clicked it takes the variables taken from fetch.php and directs the user to a page such as "/user/view/?id=VAR_ID_NUMBER"

Am I approaching this the wrong way, or doing it wrong? Can anyone help? :)

Comment: For the love of webservers, please don't perform network activity in an unthrottled mousemove callback!

Comment: Mouse-move AJAX calls can kill your server quick.
Do you use the data, returned form the mousemove Ajax call or do you want to have it ready for mouse click ?
Because, it's better to have only mouse click to fetch it's data and redirect.

Comment: Oh, ignore my last comment. I see that you're using one image div.

Comment: Can you post your code for fetch.php? Is it returning a validly formatted JSON result?

Comment: But please please please please, throttle the mousemove function.

Comment: Okay, I've added in the fetch.php but what do you mean by throttle the mousemove function?? Would it make more sense to take Chris's approach and just use block ID's and do it the old fashioned way?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your PHP code is not returning any information.

Comment: By throttle the mousemove function, I mean don't execute an $.ajax request with every mousemove event. Mousemove will send out hundreds/thousands of events, and you don't want to produce that many network requests, when they'll all just be thrown away or contain duplicate information. A common idiom for this is to use a setTimeout callback, and to reset the setTimeout timer if another event occurs before the timer expires. This results in the callback only occurring when the mouse settles in a particular place after some time (500ms for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the comments about *not* doing a fetch with every mousemove. Bad bad bad idea. Use some throttling.

That said, the problem is, you're not using the result in any way in the success function.

Your PHP function doesn't return anything to the browser. PHP variables do not magically become available to your client-side JavaScript. PHP simply runs, produces an HTML page as output, and sends it to the browser. The browser then parses the information that was sent to it as appropriate.

You need to modify your fetch.php to produce some properly formatted JSON string with the data you need. It would look something like `{ userid: 2837 }`. For example, try:

```
echo "{ userid: $user_id, username: $user_name }";
```

In your success callback, the first argument jQuery will pass to that function will be the result of parsing the (hopefully properly formatted) JSON result so that it becomes a proper JavaScript object. Then, in the success callback, you can use the result, in a way such as:

```
//data will contain a JavaScript object that was generate from the JSON
//string the fetch.php produce, *iff* it generated a properly formatted
//JSON string.
function(data) { 
  $("#user_id_area").html(data.user_id);
}
```

Modify your HTML example as follows:

```
User ID: <span id="user_id_area">&nbsp;</span>
```

Where showHover is a helper function that actually shows the hover.

Here is a pattern for throttling the mousemove function:

```
jQuery.fn.elementlocation = function() {

    var curleft = 0;
    var curtop = 0;

    var obj = this;

    do {

    curleft += obj.attr('offsetLeft');
    curtop += obj.attr('offsetTop');

    obj = obj.offsetParent();

    } while ( obj.attr('tagName') != 'BODY' );


        return ( {x:curleft, y:curtop} );

};


$(document).ready( function() {

    var updatetimer = null;
    $("#gdimage").mousemove( function( eventObj ) {
        clearTimer(updatetimer);
        setTimeout(function() { update_hover(eventObj.pageX, eventObj.pageY); }, 500);
    }


    var update_hover = function(pageX, pageY) {
        var location = $("#gdimage").elementlocation();
        var x = pageX - location.x;
        var y = pageY - location.y;

        x = x / 5;
        y = y / 5;

        x = (Math.floor( x ) + 1);
        y = (Math.floor( y ) + 1);

        if (y > 1) {

            block = (y * 200) - 200;
            block = block + x;

        } else {

            block = x;

        }

        $("#block").text( block );
        $("#x_coords").text( x );
        $("#y_coords").text( y );

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "fetch.php",
            data: "x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                //If you're using Chrome or Firefox+Firebug
                //Uncomment the following line to get debugging info
                //console.log("Name: "+data.username);
                $("#user_name_area").html(data.username);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: So I've added in echo - "{ userid: $user_id, username: $user_name }"; - to the PHP and then in the jQuery changed - success: function(data) { } - TO - function(data) { showHover(data.userid, data.username); } - ALSO - adding in - <div id="showHover"></span> - in the HTML for somwhere the information can be displayed? Is that right? Cause the div is there but no information is placed in there.

Comment: I have also tried it this way the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820303/a-fast-way-or-alternate-way-to-dynamically-load-40000-links-in-an-image-map - but the load time was a little longer than I wanted. Could this be another approach that could work. BTW thank you for your help so far though guys!! :D

Comment: No no, showHover was to be a function that you implemented yourself that updates the hover div and makes it visible. ---- So, I've updated my example to show you one possible way that you can modify the information in the hover div.

Comment: Hmm... I've updated my question with the code I have now - haven't yet added the time delay on the mouse move yet. As of now, I'm not getting any information appear in the user_name_area ? I'm also a little confused on where to put the time delay code you posted. I know in the jQuery but I'm not sure what to keep and what to delete. Sorry! :/

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to guide you in the right direction to make the code you need. I've updated the example so that it's a little more explicit. I haven't tested it, so there may be a typo or bug. Incidentally, I would *highly* suggest taking some time to learn more about JavaScript and client-side programming, as well as debugging techniques to help you. It will make your life much easier moving forward.

Comment: Yeah, I'm slowly trying to build on my client-side knowledge and my current project is definitely trying my patience :P Okay, I've also added an if statement around the ajax call (original post updated). When I view the fetch.php it echos the username etc but the $("#user_id/name_area").html(data.user_name/id); doesn't seem to bring anything back in the user id/name span tags.

Comment: Also, using what about using load(); instead of ajax(); ? Could that work at all?

Comment: I've updated my code once again, with json_code in the fetch.php file and got rid of the if statement around my ajax call since it was affecting the results. Currently it is bring back the correct usernames, now I just need to add the time delay to help server load!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the PHP code? Do you use `json_encode` on the return data?

An alternative would be to simply make the image a background to a `<div>` container and arrange `<a>` elements in the `<div>` where you need them then simply bind with jQuery to their click handler.

This also has benefits if the browser does not support jQuery or javascript as you can actually put the URL you need in the `HREF` attribute of the anchor.  This way if jQuery is not enabled the link will be loaded normally.

A skeleton implementation would look like this:

Example CSS

```
#imagecontainer {
background-image: url('gd_image.php'); 
width: 1000px; 
height: 1000px;
position: relative;
}

#imagecontainer a {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
}

#block1 {
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}

#block2 {
left: 100px;
top: 0px;
}
```

Example HTML

```
<div id="imagecontainer">
<a href="" id="block1"></a>
<a href="" id="block2"></a>
</div>
```

Example jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#block1").click(function(){ /* do what you need here */ });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that take a while to load though, since you would have 40000 #block ID's in the CSS, as well as 40000 <a> tags in the HTML and 40000 queries in the PHP/MySQL?

Comment: It'll be smaller than an image containing 4000 user profile pictures! You can compress the CSS using CSS selectors, or you can make the `<a>` tags float left so they fill up naturally

Comment: This will be like a big red button with "DDoS me, Please!" label.

Comment: I could make them fill up by floating them, except the location is chosen by the user upon sign up, so that option won't work.

@Radoslav, I'm not sure why you've written DDoS, it's users who signup to my site and become a member. And are placed on the home page image so people can keep in contact and see who is currently active within an online game... unless I'm mis-understood?

Comment: While it's less data than a large image, it will be much more taxing on a user's browsers to render so many individual DOM elements.